# Is it worth using a JSON column type, even if it's only used for simple serialized strings or integers?

Tags: mysql, innodb, json, varchar

I have a table with an unidexed `value` column of `VARCHAR(1024)`, and I've used my ORM to automatically convert it to and from JSON. The entire reason for this is I want it to be able to store any data type, so I can give it an integer or string, and it'll be able to handle it without issue.

Here's some information on the existing live table:

- Nearly 60k records
- Table size is 10MB (7.5MB data, 2.5MB index)
- The average length of the value column is 141 characters
- Almost all of the values are raw strings
- The remaining few dozen values are either floats or integers
- I may potentially include lists/dictionaries in the future

Would using the `JSON` column open up some future possibilities without particularly affecting things, or would it likely result in considerably worse storage/performance than a large `VARCHAR`?

I don't believe storage should be an issue ([here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/storage-requirements.html#data-types-storage-reqs-json) says the overhead for a string is up to 14 bytes, so in a worst case scenario, that's <1MB), but I'm mainly worried about performance with it being the equivalent of `LONGTEXT`. Will it act similar to `VARCHAR` with the smaller values, or am I going to be getting separate blocks of data that will be super slow to include in queries?

**Edit for requested info**:

The data is for crash tracking, where it logs certain user actions in a program, such as opening a file or loading a plugin, alongside any extra data (eg. file path or plugin name).

Example of ORM syntax:

1. Create record: `action_info = ActionInfo('FILE_OPEN')`
2. Add data: `action_info.data['path'] = 'C:/path/to/file`
3. Behind the scenes, search for or create `action_data = ActionData(key='path', value=json.dumps('C:/path/to/file'))`.
4. Behind the scenes, create `ActionLink(info=action_info, data=action_data)` to map the values together.

There are both "actions" and "sessions" which are handled almost identically, so to keep things simple, I'll just show the CREATE TABLE of the "sessions" side of it (copied out of MySQL Workbench). The main difference is one "session" can have multiple "actions".

```
CREATE TABLE `session_info` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  `activity` datetime(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hash` (`hash`),
  KEY `ix_session_info_date` (`date`),
  KEY `ix_session_info_activity` (`activity`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=236987 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `session_data` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(1024) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `hash` binary(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hash` (`hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1003 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `session_link` (
  `info_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `data_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`info_id`,`data_id`),
  KEY `data_id` (`data_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `session_link_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`info_id`) REFERENCES `session_info` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `session_link_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`data_id`) REFERENCES `session_data` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

To be clear, my question was specifically on the `session_data.value` / `action_data.value` column.

Number of records:

- session_info: 237778
- session_data: 997
- session_link: 1577104
- action_info: 15471345
- action_data: 62610
- action_link: 23179982

As to selects, as of right now I'm only using exact values, so I can use the indexed `session_data.hash` to perform a quick lookup (`.where(SessionData.hash==hash_kv(key, value))` instead of `.where(Sessiondata.key==key, SessionData.value==value)`).

The ORM itself emits this query to fetch all the data records at once:

```
SELECT session_link.info_id AS session_link_info_id, session_link.data_id AS session_link_data_id, session_data_1.id AS session_data_1_id, session_data_1.`key` AS session_data_1_key, session_data_1.value AS session_data_1_value, session_data_1.hash AS session_data_1_hash
FROM session_link LEFT OUTER JOIN session_data AS session_data_1 ON session_data_1.id = session_link.data_id
WHERE %(param_1)s = session_link.info_id
```

Sorry if I added a bit much needless detail - I wasn't quite sure what would be useful and what wouldn't.

Comment: the main question is, do you need to  do manipulation of the data, or doo you store them and only grab them.quering json is mostly more complicated than querying a normalized table(s), the same goes for updates and deletes

Comment: As of right now, I'm either just grabbing them or using the hash to query. My idea was that json could potentially improve things in the future if I needed to store different data types and do more advanced queries (it's a big "if" to be fair), and since I'm due to reset the database, it's now or never :)

Comment: now there exsits a index on json, but i suggest you make some  rows and try to query them and then update and delete after specific critieria and see how it handles. like i tried to convey it gets really heavy. alsp there is something like mongodb, that specializes in json

Comment: I don't plan on indexing the column for the record, I toyed with the idea but I decided on keeping the hash column after doing some quick tests. If you're saying json is considerably more heavy than varchar, then it definitely sounds like my best bet is sticking with the current method. It's a little hard to test performance as my queries rely on another table with millions of values, everything is pretty much instant if I try with a small sample of the full data set.

Comment: ORMs aim for flexibility, not scaling, nor performance.  There is no general answer to your question (in spite of the nice details you provided); please elaborate on the type of data and, importantly, the likely selects.  Dataset types:  log / real estate / sensors / company information / people / etc.

Comment: And, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  It sounds like that 60K-row table is attributes for a few thousand "entities".  If so, please provide info on that table, too.

Comment: Hey, cheers, I added some extra info for you, not sure if it'd be of too much help however.